# Woothemes social/connect buttons

Tags: wordpress, woothemes

I need to insert only the social / connect buttons which are contained in the woo_subscribe_connect function in a different place in my theme (before the content).

I have worked out that to include this function I can do this:

```
add_action( 'woo_content_before', 'my_woo_subscribe_connect_hook' );

function my_woo_subscribe_connect_hook() { ?>
    <div class="col-full" align="right"> <?php woo_subscribe_connect(); ?></div>
<?php }
```

However, this shows both the social connect buttons AND the subscribe form, plus latest blog posts.
I need a simple function that just displays the social buttons.

Can anyone help?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure which Wootheme you are using, but there are settings in the theme options that will allow you to disable related posts as well as a newsletter sign up and contact form.